# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column j1_0.id does not exist error in springboot when trying to get data from database view

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, database-view

```
``package mk.ukim.finki.npb_proekt_be.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Data
@Immutable
@Table(name = "job_ads", schema = "public")
@Subselect("select * from public.job_ads")
public class JobAds implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    private Integer jobad_id;


    private String jobdescription;


    private Integer worklocationid;


    private String worklocation;


    private Integer placeid;


    private String placename;
}
`


`
```

This is my class which is mapped from a view that contains all fields except id, because it's view it doesn't have id.
Here is the schema . [shema from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4WK.png).

So i am trying to get data from this view but it keeps getting some error like in the title please help.

Also the repository is this

```
package mk.ukim.finki.npb_proekt_be.repository;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import mk.ukim.finki.npb_proekt_be.model.JobAds;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface JobAdsRepo extends JpaRepository<JobAds, String> {
}
```

I am trying to get view data and show it on the frontend. The view also has a lot of rows so i am expecting some list with 100 rows.